# I got probrem to launch some applications libharfbuzz.so.0 error(Kali)

Tags: kali-linux

```
root@kali:/home/toor# uname -a
Linux kali 4.13.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.13.4-1kali1 (2017-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I tryed launching application,It got error to couldnt work.
The probrem happens in  kdenlive audacious deluge keepnote bleachbit ...andmore.
How can i fix it?

```
toor@kali:~$ kdenlive
KTranscript: Loaded module: /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_SCRIPTS/ki18n5/ki18n5.js
kdenlive: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

toor@kali:~$ audacious
ERROR plugin-load.cc:72 [plugin_load]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/audacious/General/gtkui.so could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
WARNING plugin-init.cc:102 [start_plugin]: GTK インターフェイス failed to start.
ERROR plugin-load.cc:72 [plugin_load]: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/audacious/General/skins.so could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
WARNING plugin-init.cc:102 [start_plugin]: Winamp クラシックインターフェイス failed to start.
ERROR plugin-init.cc:147 [start_required]: No interface plugin found.
(Did you forget to install audacious-plugins?)
中止

toor@kali:~$ deluge
[ERROR   ] 04:04:12 ui:171 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/ui.py", line 152, in __init__
    from deluge.ui.gtkui.gtkui import GtkUI
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gtkui import start
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/gtkui.py", line 50, in <module>
    reactor = gtk2reactor.install()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/gtk2reactor.py", line 99, in install
    reactor = Gtk2Reactor(useGtk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/gtk2reactor.py", line 71, in __init__
    import gtk as _gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
[ERROR   ] 04:04:12 ui:172 There was an error whilst launching the request UI: gtk
[ERROR   ] 04:04:12 ui:173 Look at the traceback above for more information.

toor@kali:~$ keepnote
==============================================
KeepNote 0.7.8: Fri Oct 13 04:04:33 2017
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/keepnote", line 437, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/bin/keepnote", line 423, in main
    start_gui(argv, options, args, cmd_exec)
  File "/usr/bin/keepnote", line 259, in start_gui
    import keepnote.gui
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keepnote/gui/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from gtk import gdk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
toor@kali:~$ bleachbit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bleachbit", line 42, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should use and share the result  the command  "ldd kdenlive" for know if not a library path problem

Comment: [https://pastebin.com/ZF7udpzP](https://pastebin.com/ZF7udpzP)
thx,it's the result.

Comment: [https://pastebin.com/EWJRApyj](https://pastebin.com/EWJRApyj)and it is audacious's

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `libharfbuzz-dev`.

`sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev`

Would you post you output after installing that library?

Please try to install this, libQt5XcbQpa.

Both libraries are in this output report as you post.

Wish this help.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot. but it couldnt solved...